# Worpress - run script once per session with 10 sec dealay

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have a js script ready to upload to a website based on wordpress, but I have to set it to run once per session and to have a 10-second delay. Anyone can help me?

Comment: "10 second delay" -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout

Comment: "once per session" -> do a bit of research, please, that should be anything but a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Use **setInterval** method inside JS Script, setInterval(method, time); i.e. setInterval(displayHello, 1000); OR use recursive **setTimeout()** to run the script in intervals.